# useRef({ }) object.current has keys with html elements but returns undefined when attempting to access the keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
let newRefObj = useRef({});
newRefObj.current = {};

//Object.keys(menuData) returns ['angus_burger', 'chicken_sandwiches', 'fish_veg', 'specials', 'salads', 'sides_bevs']

let menuDataArr = Object.keys(menuData).map(categoryID => {
    menuData[categoryID]['eleRef'] = newRefObj.current[categoryID];

    //^newRefObj.current[categoryID] returns undefined even though if I were to console.log(newRefObj.current), 
    the console shows it has keys with the html element 

    return menuData[categoryID];
})

<MenuCategory
    key={uuid()}
    header={category.header}
    note={category.note}
    menuItems={category.menuItems}

    //category.categoryID returns one of the keys above (ie: category.categoryID = 'angus burger')

    ref={el => newRefObj.current[category.categoryID] = el}
    categoryID={category.categoryID}
 />
```

So I'm not sure what's going on here as after the parent component that runs the above code renders, my ref object (newRefObj.current) returns an object with keys in it that all return html element references. However, if I were to console.log(newRefObj.current.angus_burgers) or any other key, it returns undefined. Am I not understanding something about useRef objects?

Sorry if I'm not clear enough. Just finding this a bit strange.

Edit: (whole component)

```
export default function Menu(props){
let newRefObj = useRef({});
newRefObj.current = {};

let menuDataArr = Object.keys(menuData).map(categoryID => {
    console.log(newRefObj.current.sides_bevs, categoryID)
    menuData[categoryID]['eleRef'] = newRefObj.current[categoryID];
    return menuData[categoryID];
})

let [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory] = useState('');
function executeScroll(ref){
    window.scrollTo({left: 0, top: ref.current.offsetTop - 100, behavior: 'smooth'})
    setCurrentCategory(ref.current.dataset.categoryid)
}

return (
    <div className="Menu">
        <div className="Menu-headerArea">
            <p>Focused on every detail, <span className="Menu-brand">Charred</span> brings our backyard to <span>you</span></p>
        </div>
        <div className="Menu-headerArea Menu-headerArea--secondary">
            <i className="fas fa-hamburger"></i>
            <h3>The Menu</h3>
            <MenuCategoryBtns
                menuDataArr={menuDataArr}
                executeScroll={executeScroll} 
                currentCategory={currentCategory} 
            />
        </div>
        <div className="Menu-board">
            {menuDataArr.map(category => (
                <MenuCategory
                    key={uuid()}
                    header={category.header}
                    note={category.note}
                    menuItems={category.menuItems}
                    ref={el => newRefObj.current[category.categoryID] = el}
                    categoryID={category.categoryID}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: Can you update your question to include complete component code so it's clearer when you are console logging the ref value? From what I can tell how you are setting the ref value each `MenyCategory` has to render at least once in order to get the `el` value to save. If you are logging *before* first render then OFC it'll all be undefined.

Comment: @DrewReese I've updated with the whole component. I know its not an issue of logging before it renders. If I console.log(newRefObj.current), I do get a log that is undefined, but after the first render I get another log where it is defined with all the appropriate keys with the appropriate refs. It is when I console.log(newRefObj.current[key]), even after the first render it is still undefined. Even though console.log(newRefObj.current), on the same line, returns what its supposed to.

Comment: Why the `newRefObj.current = {};` right after `useRef` ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli to empty newRefObj.current on re-renders. useRef objects maintain their data through re-renders so I want to clear it on every re-render before data gets assigned to it. Just a simple clean up is all.

Comment: @QuanCao why use a ref then ? The whole point of using refs is that the maintain their value between renders.

Comment: Refs can also be used to access DOMNodes, such as the use of accessing an element's `offsetTop` value for scrolling.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli like Drew said, I simply need the ref to access the element from the DOM to get element properties. In the above case, I'm using it for scroll events.

Answer (score 0):

Your `menuData[categoryID]['eleRef'] = newRefObj.current[categoryID];` will always result to setting `undefined` because at the moment you run it, the `newRefObj.current` is empty (*since you explicitly do `newRefObj.current = {};` right before you set the `menuDataArr`*)

Comment: This is not correct. This is standard practice when using an empty array or empty object when initializing useRef()

Comment: @QuanCao what is standard practice ? Reseting the `current` property of a ref ? I doubt that, but would appreciate any links you have on this. Regardless, my answer still stands since your are trying to access properties of the `newRefObj.current` right after clearing it. Try to run the code in your mind sequentially and you will understand that there is no way for `newRefObj.current[categoryID];` to return anything if the previous line is `newRefObj.current={}`.